# Shell command not executed by rails action

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, shell, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm pretty new to ruby and ruby on rails so please pardon me if this might sound very trivial to you. 
I want to run a shell command on button click from my rails application. I've created required view and action, and also updated my `routes.rb` file to post to the required view. I also have defined a function in my model, which will finally be executing the shell command. Everything runs smoothly, with the workflow going as planned, but the command is not executed. Also, the app shows no error. Following are the snippets of my respective model, action and controller. I'am using Rails 4.1.1, with Ruby-2.1.2, on a Ubuntu 12.04 LTS.

Here is my routes file. I have overwritten the default `/post` route from `directory#create` to 'directory#create_directory'.

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do


match '/directories', to: 'directories#create_directory', via: 'post'

resources :directories
```

Model : The command i want to execute is specified in this function.

```
class Directory < ActiveRecord::Base
 def self.create_directory
  `mkdir dummy_dir`
 end
end
```

Custom controller-action

```
def create_directory
  @directory = Directory.create_directory
end
```

New directory view(generated using scaffolding)- This is the page where we land from the index page, after we click on create a new directory option. I've added a `button_to`, clicking on which redirects me to my custom action `create_directory`.

```
<h1>New Directory</h1>

<%= button_to "Create Directory", 
url_for( :action => "create_directory", :controller=> :directories ),:remote=>true %>

<%= link_to 'Back', directories_path %>
```

I also have created a dummy view for create_directory action. I land on this view in the end.
Well, everything runs smoothly without giving any error, but the directory is not created. Any suggestions as to where i might be going wrong.
Thanks in advance

Comment: resources :directorys, the plural is directories.

Comment: Try to check the output of `mkdir dummy_dir`.

Comment: yes, i checked. It's working fine when i run it in my terminal, and creates directory accordingly.

Comment: No. You should check it's output in session. There could be an error. Try something like `p 'mkdir dummy_dir'`

Comment: Your web server should be running as a user with almost no permissions at all so it better not have permission to create a directory in its current working directory.

Comment: yup, it was the problem of permissions only. I tweaked the code such that now it runs the command with root user permissions, and now it creates the directory.